# Neural Networks (input and output layers)

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

When dealing with muticlass classification, is it always that the number of nodes (which are vectors) in the input layer excluding bias is the same as the number of nodes in the output layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The input layer ingests the features. The output layer makes predictions for classes. The number of features and classes does not need to be the same; it also depends on how exactly you model the multiple classes output.

Answer (score 0):

Lars Kotthoff is right. However, when you are using an artificial neural network to build an [autoencoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder), you will want to have the same number of input and output nodes, and you will want the output nodes to learn the values of the input nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Nope,

Usually number of input unites equals to number of features you are going use for training the NN classifier.

Size of the output layer equals to number of classes in the dataset. Further, if dataset has two classes only just one output unit is enough for discriminating these two classes.

Answer (score 0):

The ANN output layer has a node for each class: if you have 3 classes, you use 3 nodes. The input layer (often called a feature vector) has a node for each feature used for prediction and usually an extra bias node. You usually need only 1 hidden layer, and discerning its ideal size tricky.

Having too many hidden layer nodes can result in overfitting and slow training. Having too few hidden layer nodes can result in underfitting (overgeneralizing).

Here are a few general guidelines ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140721050413/http://www.heatonresearch.com/node/707)) to start with:

- The number of hidden neurons should be between the size of the input layer and the size of the output layer.
- The number of hidden neurons should be 2/3 the size of the input layer, plus the size of the output layer.
- The number of hidden neurons should be less than twice the size of the input layer.

If you have 3 classes and an input vector of 30 features, you can start with a hidden layer of around 23 nodes. Add and remove nodes from this layer during training to reduce your error, while testing against validation data to prevent overfitting.